# How do i replace in Linux blanks with underscore between letters only, ignoring numbers

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, replace

Using Linux, i need a way to replace blanks in a string with underscores. The special point is to do this only between two letters (regardless if upper- or lowercase). Not between two numbers or a number and a letter.

Example:

```
"This is a test File of 100 MB Size - 45 of 50 files processed"
```

Output should be:

```
"This_is_a_test_File_of 100 MB_Size - 45 of 50 files_processed"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

I tried a lot of sed regex combinations, but none of them did the job. 
Seems a bit tricky.

```
sed 's/\([a-z]\)[[:space:]]\([A-Z]\)/_/g'
sed 's/\([a-z]\) \([A-Z]\)/_/g'
```

Comment: Probably the easiest would be `sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\) \([[:alpha:]]\)/\1_\2/g' file | sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\) \([[:alpha:]]\)/\1_\2/g'`. The sed command is piped and run twice because there are one letter words in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way that puts hyphens around digits and that plays with word boundaries:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9_])/-\1-/g;s/\b \b/_/g;s/-([0-9_])-/\1/g' file
```

---

Or more direct with perl:

```
perl -pe's/\pL\K (?=\pL)/_/g' file
```

Comment: That SED pattern seems to do the job perfectly! It also seems to handle single blank exclusively, not working on multiple blank.

Thanks a lot!

`code`
echo "hello test  doublespace 123 456 10g 1lah" | sed -E 's/([0-9_])/-\1-/g;s/\b \b/_/g;s/-([0-9_])-/\1/g'

hello_test  doublespace 123 456 10g 1lah

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
sed ':A;s/\([[:alpha:]]\) \([[:alpha:]]\)/\1_\2/;tA' file
```

Or

```
sed ':A;s/\([[:alpha:]]\)[[:space:]]\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1_\2/;tA' file
```

The point is that you match and capture a letter into Group 1 with the first `\([[:alpha:]]\)`, then match a space (or whitespace with `[[:space:]]`), and then match and capture into Group 2 a letter (with the second `\([[:alpha:]]\)`), replace this match with the contents of Group 1 (`\1`), `_` and Group 2 contents (`\2`), and then get back to search for a match after the preceding match start.

Note your approach would partly work if you added `\1` and `\2` placeholders to your RHS at right places, but the fact there are one-letter words would prevent it from working. However, if you pipe the second idedentical sed command you would get the expected output:

```
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\) \([[:alpha:]]\)/\1_\2/g' file | sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\) \([[:alpha:]]\)/\1_\2/g'
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/O764OB).

Comment: or using 1 call to sed without a pipe: `sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\) \([[:alpha:]]\)/\1_\2/g; s//\1_\2/g'`